# JPA Repository - findLast returning NonUniqueResultException?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `JpaRepository` function that looks like this:

```
fun findLastByOrganisationAndFileType(organisation: Organisation, fileType: FileType) : OrganisationFile?
```

For some reason though, when I have 2 files of the same type for an organisation, I receive the following error:

> javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2

I know it's not unique, but I don't know why it needs to be, afterall it's using findLast, rather than find.

Does it need an order by to be specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like in SQL calling `limit` or equivalent without an ordering does not make much sense without ordering (other than getting a sample of data), here you also need to specify `OrderBy` part of the method name:

```
fun findLastByOrganisationAndFileTypeOrderBySomeField(organisation: Organisation, fileType: FileType) : OrganisationFile?
```